# Message array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

That might be a fool question, but I need to know how to solve this:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\search_view.php on line 248
Why am I getting this message, what can I do to solve it?

```
echo'<div id="thumb"> 

'.$ids = array();
$ids[] = $results['idGames'];  
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {

$id = $ids[$i];




$v  = $results['total_votes'];
$tv = $results['total_value'];
if ($v)
    $rat = $tv / $v;
else
    $rat = 0;



$j  = $ids[$i];
$id = $ids[$i];
echo '<div class="topcontentstar">

    <div id="' . $id . '" class="">';
for ($k = 1; $k < 6; $k++) {
 if ($rat + 1 > $k)
    $class = "" . $k . "  ratings_stars_index ratings_vote";
    else
    $class = "" . $k . " ratings_stars_index ratings_blank";
     echo '<div class="' . $class . '"></div>';
}
echo ' 
</div>
    </div></div>;
```

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) more suit array looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
echo'<div id="thumb"> 
(line 248) '.$ids = array();
```

Basically, you can't concatenate array with a string and that's why the error appears.

To fix the error, you can separate the array declaration into a separate line:

```
echo'<div id="thumb">';
$ids = array();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great it works, but know is echoing a ";" along the content, was that suppose to happen?

Comment: @MariangelaVidotto: not really. See the last line of your code: `</div></div>;` -- that might be the issue. :-)

Comment: Alright now it's perfect, thank you for the help, I really appreciate it, thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

Because in this part of code you tried to convert an array to string via concatenation

```
echo'<div id="thumb"> 
(line 248) '.$ids = array();
```

Separate them: `$ids = array()`

```
echo'<div id="thumb"> 
(line 248) ';
$ids = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo'<div id="thumb"> 


(line 248) '.$ids = array();
```

You are concatenating a string and an array, just as the errors says. You are echoing the string, and appending the array `$ids` to that. Because assigning a value gets a higher precedence than concatenating things, `$ids` is already an array.

Answer (score -1):

As a side note, I can see a problem in your last few lines:

```
echo ' 
</div>
    </div></div>;
```

Should be:

```
echo '</div></div></div>';
```

Comment: -1. Having newlines in a single quoted string is not illegal PHP syntax.

Comment: But you forgot ' character